# npm i behaving differently for different node version

Tags: node.js, npm

I have in package.json as below

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-split-pane": "^0.1.92",
```

## with the below configuration.

```
$ node --version
v12.22.1
$ npm --version
6.14.12
```

when i do `npm install`

I see in the package-lock.json

```
    "@types/react": {
      "version": "17.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/react/-/react-17.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-wYOUxIgs2HZZ0ACNiIayItyluADNbONl7kt8lkLjVK8IitMH5QMyAh75Fwhmo37r1m7L2JaFj03sIfxBVDvRAg==",
      "requires": {
        "@types/prop-types": "*",
        "@types/scheduler": "*",
        "csstype": "^3.0.2"
      }
    },
    "@types/react-dom": {
      "version": "17.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/react-dom/-/react-dom-17.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-4NnJbCeWE+8YBzupn/YrJxZ8VnjcJq5iR1laqQ1vkpQgBiA7bwk0Rp24fxsdNinzJY2U+HHS4dJJDPdoMjdJ7w==",
      "requires": {
        "@types/react": "*"
      }
    },
    "react-split-pane": {
      "version": "0.1.92",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-split-pane/-/react-split-pane-0.1.92.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-GfXP1xSzLMcLJI5BM36Vh7GgZBpy+U/X0no+VM3fxayv+p1Jly5HpMofZJraeaMl73b3hvlr+N9zJKvLB/uz9w==",
      "requires": {
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react-lifecycles-compat": "^3.0.4",
        "react-style-proptype": "^3.2.2"
      }
    },
```

and when i do `npm ci` i see  there are no errors

and when i do `npm ls -a` i see

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.0.0-0, required by react-split-pane@0.1.92
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@^16.0.0-0, required by react-split-pane@0.1.92
```

## whereas with the below configuration

```
$ node --version
v18.19.0
$ npm --version   
10.2.3
```

when i try `npm i`  it fails.

```
╰─$ npm i                   
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sqlpad-front-end@6.6.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0-0" from react-split-pane@0.1.92
npm ERR! node_modules/react-split-pane
npm ERR!   react-split-pane@"^0.1.92" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/simha/.npm/_logs/2024-02-11T03_56_08_689Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/simha/.npm/_logs/2024-02-11T03_56_08_689Z-debug-0.log
```

I am trying to upgrade from `node 12` to `node 18`  and thats the time i am facing this issue.

I am ok that in `node 12` even though we have this issue `dep missing: react@^16.0.0-0, required by react-split-pane@0.1.92` it still got installed smooth.

but in `node 18` things look not installing at all and only option looks like using `--force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the --legacy-peer-deps flag:
add --legacy-peer-deps to your npm install or npm ci command. This tells npm to handle peer dependencies the way version 6 did, essentially bypassing the conflict and continuing with your installation. It's a quick workaround, though it doesn't solve the root cause of the version discrepancies.

to isntall the legacy-peer-deps:
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Or:
Use the --force flag:
This is another method, somewhat similar to the first, but it takes a more heavy-handed approach.

to install:
npm install --force